# How to suppress a StyleCop warning of entire namespace files

Tags: c#, stylecop

I'm using Style Cop version 4.7. Global suppression don't work for every member of selected namespace.

I have two files in the same namespace (StyleCopSample.Test).
When I set suppress message in the first file, messages are suppressing only for this file, but the second file still gets a warnings.

Content of the first file:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("CSharp.DocumentationRules", "*", Scope = "Namespace", Target = "StyleCopSample.Test")]

namespace StyleCopSample.Test
{
  class TestFirst {}
}
```

Content of the second file:

```
namespace StyleCopSample.Test
{
  class TestSecond {}
}
```

I don't want to describe suppress message attribute for every physical file of the same namespace. Any ideas?

Thanks for Your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SuppressMessage` directive will only process the current file (see the comments in [this stylecop issue](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7352)).

You could possibly achieve what you want via [file lists](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists&referringTitle=Documentation), although this will work best if there are only a few files you want to apply this exclusion to. If you want this applied to all files in a particular project, then the easiest way may be to simply modify the settings via the settings dialog as already mentioned.

Alternatively, you could put all the namespace related files into a separate folder, and have a custom settings file in that folder to exclude these rules from those particular files.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's better just to disable the documentation rules on the StyleCop settings file.

Just open the settings dialog from the project context menu.

[image: Menu item]

And then uncheck the 'Documentation Rules' checkbox.

[image: uncheck this item]